# youtube video download question error and empty query problem

Tags: php

[enter link description here](https://www.onlinevideoindirme.com/index.php)

Hello there,
i have two problems
1. Empty link does not give error when entering, how can I add it.
2. Does not download 1080p video only supports up to 720p How can I solve it? Waiting for immediate help.

Thank you very much in advance.

```html
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');


$thumb = $title = '';
$iArray = array(18 => "MP4 360p video indir", 22 => "MP4 720p | Video İndirr", 36 => "3GP 240p | Video İndir", 43 => "MP4 480p | Video İndir", 26 => "MP4 1080p | Video İndir");



function getID($url) {
 $pattern = '%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i';
 if (preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches)) return $matches[1];
 else exit(json_encode(array(
 'Code' => '404', 
 'Status' => 'Error', 
 'Message' => 'Video ID Bulunamadı.',
 'HTMLGui' => '
 <div class="alert alert-purple alert-icon alert-close alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <i class="font-icon font-icon-warning"></i>
        Uyarı: Video Bulunamadı! Lütfen Doğru Bir link yapıştırınız!
       </div>'
 )));
}
function cURL($url) {
 $ch = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
 $response = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 return $response;
}
function getFunction($html) {
 if (preg_match('/signature",([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\(/', $html, $matches)) {
  $fname = $matches[1];
  if (preg_match("/{$fname}=function\([a-z]+\){(.*?)}/", $html, $matches)) {
   $t = $matches[1];
   if (preg_match_all('/([a-z0-9]{2})\.([a-z0-9]{2})\([^,]+,(\d+)\)/i', $t, $matches) != false) {
    $fArray = $matches[2];
    preg_match_all('/('.implode('|', $fArray).'):function(.*?)\}/m', $html, $matches2, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    $mArray = array();
    foreach($matches2 as $j) {
     if (strpos($j[2], "splice") !== false) $mArray[$j[1]] = "splice";
     else if (strpos($j[2], "a.length") !== false) $mArray[$j[1]] = "swap";
     else if (strpos($j[2], "reverse") !== false) $mArray[$j[1]] = "reverse";
    }
    $method = array();
    if (is_array($matches[2])) {
     foreach($matches[2] as $index => $name) {
      $method[] = array($mArray[$name],$matches[4][$index]);
     }
    }
    return $method;
   }
  }
 }
 return false;
}
function getPlayer($html) {
 if (preg_match('@<script\s*src="([^"]+player[^"]+js)@', $html, $matches)) return getFunction(cURL("https://www.youtube.com".$matches[1]));
 return false;
}
function deCipher($signature, $method) {
 foreach($method as $j) {
  $c = $j[0];
  $v = $j[1];
  if ($c == 'swap') {
   $t = $signature[0];
   $signature[0] = $signature[$v % strlen($signature)];
   $signature[$v] = $t;
  }
  else if ($c == 'splice') $signature = substr($signature, $v);
  else if ($c == 'reverse') $signature = strrev($signature);
 }
 return trim($signature);
}
function getDownload($id) {
 global $iArray, $title, $thumb;
 $method = $result = array();
 $html = cURL('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$id);
 if (strpos($html, 'player-age-gate-content') !== false) return false;
 $thumb = 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/'.$id.'/hqdefault.jpg';
 if (preg_match("/<title>(.+?)<\/title>/is", $html, $matches)) $title = str_replace(' - YouTube', '', $matches[1]);
 if (preg_match('@url_encoded_fmt_stream_map["\']:\s*["\']([^"\'\s]*)@', $html, $matches)) {
  $streams = explode(",", $matches[1]);
  foreach($streams as $stream) {
   parse_str(str_replace('\u0026', '&', $stream), $data);
   $url = $data['url'];
   if (isset($data['s'])) {
    if (count($method) == 0) $method = (array)getPlayer($html);
    $url .= '&signature='.deCipher($data['s'], $method);
   }
   else if (isset($data['sig'])) $url .= '&signature='.$data['sig'];
   else if (isset($data['signature'])) $url .= '&signature='.$data['signature'];
   $itag = $data['itag'];
   $format = isset($iArray[$itag]) ? $iArray[$itag] : '-';
   if ($itag != 17) $result[$itag] = array('url' => $url, 'format' => $format, 'sig' => deCipher($data['s'], $method));
  }
 }
 return $result;
}

if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) || !isset($_POST['action']) || !isset($_POST['video_url'])) {
 exit(json_encode(array('Code' => '403', 'Status' => 'Error', 'Message' => 'Erişim Engellendi.')));
}

$result = getDownload(getID($_POST['video_url']));

if (count($result) < 1) exit(json_encode(array(
 'Code' => '405', 
 'Status' => 'Error', 
 'Message' => 'Ooops, İndirme Linki Bulunamadı.',
 'HTMLGui' => '
 <div class="alert alert-purple alert-icon alert-close alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <i class="font-icon font-icon-warning"></i>
        Uyarı: Video Bulunamadı! Lütfen Doğru Bir link yapıştırınız!
       </div>'
 )));
else {
 $HTMLGui = '<section class="widget widget-activity">';
 $HTMLGui .= '<header class="widget-header">';
 $HTMLGui .= ''.$title.'</header><br>';
 $HTMLGui .= '<img class="gallery-picture"  src="'.$thumb.'" alt="Thumb" width="300" height="200"  alt=""></section>';
 foreach ($result as $r) {
  $HTMLGui .= '<br><a class="btn btn-inline btn-success" href="'.$r['url'].'" download>'.$r['format'].'<a/><br>';
 }
 $HTMLGui .= '</div><br>';
 $HTMLGui .= '</div>';
 exit(json_encode(array(
  'Code' => '200', 
  'Status' => 'Success',
  'Message' => 'İndirme Linkleri Hazırlandı.',
  'HTMLGui' => $HTMLGui
 )));
}



     
    


?>
```

Comment: English only on this domain please.

Comment: Have you written any of this code?

Comment: i don't know i need your help, I'm a designer need a project for training.

Comment: Hello there
1. An empty link is entered and no error is sent.
2. Video types like 720p and 240p don't come.
3.Video does not download directly, we need to save as.

I need an educational study, I am waiting for your help.